# How can I execute code with render of react components in runtime

Tags: reactjs, runtime, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

Hello,

I have some react components in my project. And I would like to make the sandbox for users where they can try some properties of the components. I see this like textarea with jsx code and div with result of code.

My components have ES6 syntax and export default components and some non-default data(eg. properties of component).

I tried to transform es6 and jsx with babel then execute eval on the client side. But I couldn't connect the dependencies for component. Especially it was for non-default data.

If i try to compile bundle with webpack on the server side I work in memory file system and I have to load all dependencies from node modules there too.

Do you have any ideas how can I do it? Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Please post some of your code. This would be more helpful for users willing to answer your question.

Comment: for your situation, you need directly include `<script>` elements for babel and react in html, leaving webpack.

Comment: I compiled bundle with webpack in memory! I added all modules in memory file system. 
At now I can't compile only stylus files. I use stylus loader:
`module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.styl$/,
    loader: 'style!css!stylus'
  }]
}`
and I have build error "no such file or directory". It is ok at ordinary build and watch.